# How to make the following two optimization problems format?

Tags: math-mode

How can I reproduce this format of two optimization problems?[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Bienvenida María, deberías proporcionar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado de manera que podamos ayudarte eficazmente.

Answer (score 2):

- Welcome to TeX.SE!
- Please help us to help you: always provide what you try yourself, the best in a form of the MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which begins with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`
- Solution:

  - put each optimization problem in own minipage
  - for formating of equation is handy to use `array` package
  - for shorter and consistent code I suggest to define new math operators for Max and Min
- Since you not provide MWE for starting point I use @scd answer and modified it accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Min}{Min}

%\title{My LaTeX Document}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
(P)\quad    $\begin{array}[t]{l @{\qquad}r}
            \Max            & 8 x_1 + 3 x_2 \\
            \text{s.a.:}    &   x_1 - 6 x_2 \geq 2 \\
                            & 5 x_1 + 7 x_2=-4 \\
                            &   x_1 \leq 0 \\
                            &   x_2 \geq 0
            \end{array}$
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
(D)\quad    $\begin{array}[t]{l @{\qquad}r}
            \Min            &  2 w_1 - 4 w_2 \\
            \text{s.a.}     &    w_1 + 5 w_2 \leq 8 \\
                            & -6 w_1 + 7 w_2 \geq 3 \\
                            &    w_1 \leq 0 \\
                            &    w_2 \text{ s.r.}
            \end{array}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{My LaTeX Document}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 \begin{array}{rr}
\text { (P) } \text{ Max } & 8 x_1+3 x_2 \\
\text { s.a.: } & x_1-6 x_2 \geq 2 \\
& 5 x_1+7 x_2=-4 \\
& x_1 \leq 0 \\
& x_2 \geq 0
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 \begin{array}{rr}
& \text { (D) } \quad \operatorname{Min} \quad 2 w_1-4 w_2 \\
& \text { s.a.: } \quad w_1+5 w_2 \leq 8 \\
& -6 w_1+7 w_2 \geq 3 \\
& w_1 \leq 0 \\
& w_2 \quad \text {s.r.}
 \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

This will result in:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not meant to *reproduce* the shown format but to somehow *improve* it (although this might be very subjective).

@Zarko gave you many valuable advices (+1). I will use a self-defined command which will ensure that all of these problems are typeset the same way and takes the following arguments:

- optional argument: default is to use `\displaystyle`. Leave the optional argument empty to have `\textstyle`.
- First mandatory argument: Minimization/Maximization, so use `\min`/`\max`/`\Min`/`\Max`.
- Second mandatory argument: Objective function.
- Third mandatory argument: All your constraints. Note that this is packed into an `aligned` environment which will allow you to align your constraints.
  [image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Min}{Min}

\newcommand{\minmax}[4][\displaystyle]{
    \left\{%
    \begin{array}{@{}>{#1}r@{\quad}>{#1}l@{}}%
                   #2 & #3 \\
        \text{s.\,a.:} & \begin{aligned}[t] #4 \end{aligned}%
    \end{array}%
    \right.%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \mathrm{(P)} &\minmax{\Max}{8x_1+3x_2}{%
            x_1-6x_2    &\geq 2 \\
            5x_1 + 7x_2 &= -4   \\
            x_1         &\leq 0 \\
            x_2         &\geq 0
        }
        &
        \mathrm{(D)} & \minmax{\Min}{2w_1 - 4w_2}{%
            w_1+5w_2   &\leq 8 \\
            -6w_1+7w_2 &\geq 3 \\
            w_1        &\leq 0 \\
            w_2        &\text{ s.\,r.}
        }
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```